# Shapes drawing simple library for OpenGL, is there any?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm learning OpenGL and after reading several tutorials and books still didn't find the answer to a simple question: is there a lightweight free software library for drawing basic 2D shapes and figures in OpenGL such as arcs and ellipses for example. After having googled for 'drawing ellipse in OpenGL' I can't believe that all of several dozens recipes that I read on this topic - all of them are dealing with 'manual' construction of ellipse out of points or lines in the 'for' loop. I know that for instance GLUT or SFML have functions for drawing circles, but they are not specialized graphics libraries and also they don't draw arcs. What I need is a simple library without any context management or windowing functionality which can draw basic 2D shapes into a buffer.

Comment: It won't really be possible to learn OpenGL effectively if you are using some other library to draw basic shapes. OpenGL's primary use-case is accelerated 3D graphics, you won't find a lot of 2D primitive libraries for it (1. Because they aren't used that often, 2. Because a fair number of common 2D primitives are trivial to draw from scratch, 3. Most importantly, because OpenGL is very flexible and it is highly unlikely that any given 2D primitive library will offer everything any given application needs, it's often easier just to use OpenGL directly).

Comment: That said, as far as just circles go, you may be able to get `gluDisk()` and the other stuff in GLU to work for you, although it's arguably more convenient to just draw a circle from scratch. Your request of "drawing basic 2D shapes into a buffer" doesn't make much sense though. What kind of "buffer" are you referring to and how do you intend to have OpenGL present that "buffer"?

Comment: @JasonC - I've drawn antialased arcs and ellipses with Windows GDI using SetPixel(), but from what I've read I don't know is it possible to render with exact pixel precision in OpenGL. Some say that it's not portable from one videocard to another. But I'll try, thanks for the answer.

Comment: While you can do 2D drawing in OpenGL no problem, it isn't based on raster images, and it's not going to be the same feel as GDI. It sounds like you need to go over the basics a bit more before you start doing things with primitives and such. It's not like GDI. It's not used for the same thing, and its got a much different design philosophy. Check out http://nehe.gamedev.net/, in particular check out the "legacy tutorials" on the right. Well written, great intros.

Comment: After trying to find an easy-to-use OpenGL library that can draw basic shapes, and failing to find any, I ended up using Qt's [QPainter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html) class instead (I was trying to draw shapes in an OpenGL Qt window).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, [Cairo](http://cairographics.org) has a OpenGL backend, but that might actually be too heavyweight for your liking. But it offers a very versatile set of 2D drawing primitives and definitely is worth looking at.

Comment: Though not very lighweight, but looks exactly what I need. Thanks.

Comment: @AlBerger Be forewarned; Cairo only uses OpenGL as a back-end. It doesn't expose any of OpenGL to you. It will be counter to your stated goal of learning OpenGL. Cairo is a whole thing to learn in itself, and it just happens to use OpenGL as one of a multiple of rendering options that are essentially transparent to you.